# What Technic vehicle is this in black and red?

Tags: technic, set-identification

[image: Possible Star Wars set lego piece]

Any help with the set this piece is associated with, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I did a cross check on sets containing following pieces 'red-42003', 'blue-6632' and 'black-32250'. [This looks like the B model for set 8065.](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4622748.pdf)

Comment: ail, @Joost I synthesized your comments into the answer, hope you don't mind.